# C++: std::bind with lambda or with a function

Tags: c++, lambda, callback, stdbind

I'm trying to understand how two concepts that I understand separately, would make sense when combined together.
I'm talking about std::bind + lambda.

So I have a std::function of some kind:

```
typedef std::function<int(int)> funcType
```

And there is a function that gets an argument of this type

```
int caller(int v, funcType foo)
{
    return v + foo(v);
}
```

all of the above is given. Meaning, "caller()" is an API I need to use in order to register for some future async event.

So, I need to call caller() with a callback that I provide and to accomplish that, I can either:

1. define an old fashioned function
2. use a lambda
3. use std::bind with function
4. use std::bind with lambda

As I'm coming from C world, I understand "1" perfectly and got a pretty good understanding of "2" as well.
Now, with 3 and 4 - it's getting a little more complex to me.
What are the advantages or necessity of "3" or "4"?
Is there a difference between "3" and "4" except the obvious difference between a function and a lambda?
When it's best to use them or maybe when I should not?

So, as you can see, I don't understand the reason to use bind (I did some reading but it still hadn't sunk) - wouldn't it work without it? if not, in what cases?

And lastly - Even, when using std::bind, why should I use placeholders if all arguments (in the above example there is a single integer) to the callback will be passed to it by the external module later on, (when an event occurs and the callback will be called in the future)?

I hope I was clear.
After writing down the question, I just realized how much I don't understand... oh boy...

Comment: With the introduction of `std::function` and lambdas into the language, there's practically no reason to ever use `std::bind`. It was an attempt to implement something lambda-like in the library, before they were added to the core language. Think of it as a legacy feature maintained largely for backward compatibility with existing code.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik "*there's practically no reason to ever use `std::bind`*" - agreed. "*It was an attempt to implement something lambda-like in the library, before they were added to the core language*" - both `bind()` and lambdas were introduced in C++11. So unless the `bind()` spec was written before the lambda spec was written/finalized, then `bind()` should probably have just been left out of C++11 to begin with, IMHO. Although `bind()` does have some isolated use cases that make it slightly more efficient than lambdas. But I have never heard of anyone wanting to `bind()` a lambda.